# What is the meaning of "OptimizedOut" in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to debug my flutter code but when I try to view the value in the variable I get this message in the Debug Console:

```
day
[Sentinel kind: OptimizedOut, valueAsString: <optimized out>] from evaluateInFrame()
#0      DartDebugAdapter.evaluateRequest (package:dds/src/dap/adapters/dart.dart:993:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseDebugAdapter.handle (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:141:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I am not sure what it means since it doesn't stop execution of the code.

Here is the code I am trying to debug. It is the eventLoader: method of the table_calendar widget in my flutter app:

```
eventLoader: (day) {
        int today = day.day;
        if (events == null) return [];
        DateTime eventDateUTC = events[today].eventDate!.toUtc();

        if (day.year == events[today].eventDate!.year &&
            day.day == events[today].eventDate!.day &&
            day.month == events[today].eventDate!.month) {
          List<Events> eventList = [];
          eventList.add(events[day.day]);

          return (kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList));
        }
        return [];
      },
```

I am trying to load events into the associated day of the calendar as the calendar builds. I get the events from a Firestore db. This code is not working so I need to step through it to see if I can see why.

Thanks for any help.